# Reading files with PHP - fopen/fread

Tags: php, file, fread

```
<?php

$top = "../top.txt";
$middle = "../middle.txt";
$bottom = "../bottom.txt";
$end = "/st.txt";
$data = "/dt.txt";

$handle1 = fopen($top, "r"); 
$contents1 = fread($handle1, filesize($top)); 
fclose($handle1); 

$handle2 = fopen($end, "r"); 
$contents2 = fread($handle2, filesize($end)); 
fclose($handle2);

$handle3 = fopen($middle, "r"); 
$contents3 = fread($handle3, filesize($middle)); 
fclose($handle3);

$handle4 = fopen($data, "r"); 
$contents4 = fread($handle4, filesize($data)); 
fclose($handle4);

$handle5 = fopen($bottom, "r"); 
$contents5 = fread($handle5, filesize($bottom)); 
fclose($handle5);

echo $contents1;
echo $contents2;
echo $contents3;
echo $contents4;
echo $contents5;

?>
```

I get these errors for every one of them:

*Warning: fopen(../top.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory*

*Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for ../top.txt*

*Warning: fread(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource*

*Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource*

CHMOD in all files and folders and is set to 777

All the files exist on the server

PHP5 is installed on the server

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) might be of interest to you.

Comment: Check [include_path](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.get-include-path.php) and [open_basedir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$top = "../top.txt";
```

means that from your current position it moves one folder up, and searches for the file `top.txt`. It's same for `$middle = "../middle.txt";` and `$bottom = "../bottom.txt";`. For these two:

```
$end = "/st.txt";
$data = "/dt.txt"
```

it's searching from the root directory. Do make sure you have the files located at the places you refer them to. I may think you wanted this in the last two variables:

```
$end = "./st.txt";
$data = "./dt.txt"
```

Where `./` represents the current directory.

So, to give you more detailed example. Lets say you have your PHP file located at `/var/www/httpdocs/project/phpFile.php` then your files would be linked like:

```
$top = "/var/www/httpdocs/top.txt";
$middle = "/var/www/httpdocs/middle.txt";
$bottom = "/var/www/httpdocs/bottom.txt";

$end = "/st.txt";
$data = "/dt.txt"
```

So now notice the difference in the last two variables - they stay the same, because you've set it to be looking from root directory (`/`). Where as if you would use the linking with `./`, then the paths would be:

```
$end = "/var/www/httpdocs/project/st.txt";
$data = "/var/www/httpdocs/project/dt.txt"
```

Hope this explains it. And yes, do look into the functions other people mentioned in the answers.

Answer (score 2):

use whole path, instead of 
`../top.txt`
use
`/path/to/top.txt`

OR

you an also use 
`$top = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/../top.txt";`

Answer (score 0):

From the [PHP manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php):

> If PHP has decided that filename specifies a local file, then it will
> try to open a stream on that file. The file must be accessible to PHP,
> so you need to ensure that the file access permissions allow this
> access. If you have enabled safe mode, or open_basedir further
> restrictions may apply.

I would suggest you check [open_basedir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) and the [include path](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-include-path.php).

Here is some code to help you do that:

```
echo 'open_basedir: '.ini_get('open_basedir')."\n";
echo 'Include path: '.get_include_path()."\n";
echo 'Current path: '.__DIR__."\n";
```

With that you should be able to confirm that you are able to reach files that are within or under the directories in the open_basedir. If open_basedir is "blank" then PHP should not be enforcing any restrictions.

If all you really needed was an explanation of how file paths are usually handled by PHP (as some of the other answers seem to indicate) then [read this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) (also from the manual):

> Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given,
> the include_path specified. If the file isn't found in the
> include_path, include will finally check in the calling script's own
> directory and the current working directory before failing. The
> include construct will emit a warning if it cannot find a file; this
> is different behavior from require, which will emit a fatal error.
>
> If a path is defined — whether absolute (starting with a drive letter
> or \ on Windows, or / on Unix/Linux systems) or relative to the
> current directory (starting with . or ..) — the include_path will be
> ignored altogether. For example, if a filename begins with ../, the
> parser will look in the parent directory to find the requested file.

I assume you do no use safe mode as it is [now deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php).